# Similar book to All the Mathematics You Missed but at a graduate level that is of a reasonable size?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

[All the Mathematics You Missed](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521797071)

That is, a book that covers the motivation and important ideas of various fields of mathematics at the graduate/professional level (Measure Theory, Functional Analysis, Representation Theory, Algebraic Topology, Stochastic Analysis, Harmonic Analysis, Number Theory etc.)? I know there's the Princeton companion, but it is a massive book and not exactly suitable for light reading while commuting say.

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with the Princeton companion? It's exactly what you're asking for. Get an electronic version if portability is an issue.

Comment: I don't have anything to read electronic books and I don't intend to buy one just to read one single book.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at Zeidler: *Quantum Field Theory I* and see whether you like that. There are also two more volumes. In many parts of the books there a great explanations from a motivational point of view, for instance on cohomology.

Comment: If I carry 1000 pages around, I might as well carry the Princeton Companion, but thanks anyway.

Comment: It would be good training ... Think of a 24 kg kettlebell instead.

Comment: Professional trainers hate him! One weird trick to get that 6-packs!